# Search with multiple search parameters

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a problem with a function i wrote in vb.
The Tool opens a Excel Sheet and  has too Search two Values in that sheet.

The Excel sheet is structured as follows:

[image: Picture of an example from a table]

the Function i Wrote, looks if the Value in the Column "M" and in the Column "N" in the same Row are the same as Creterium 1 and 2. if that is so, it will return the value in the Column "O"

My Code looks like that:

```
    Function twoStrSearch(ByVal criteria1 As String, ByVal criteria2 As String, ByVal strPrimarySearchColumn As String, _
                      ByVal Offset_Krit2 As Integer, ByVal Offset_result As Integer, _
                      ByVal objWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) As VariantType
    '********************************************************************************************
    'Function for Searching an Excel Sheet.
    'If the Sheet Contains the two Criterias in the same row it will return the search Value
    '********************************************************************************************
    'Parameter:                 Explanation:         
    'criteria1                  The first comparison value
    'criteria2                  The second comparison value
    'strPrimarySearchColumn     The Name of the Row where the first comparsion value is
    'Offset_Krit2               The Offset Value where the second comparison value is
    'Offset_Ergebnis            The Offset Value where the Search result is what will be returned
    'objWorksheet               The object of the Excel Sheet that should be searched in
    '********************************************************************************************

    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim area As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    'Get's the letter of the Column
    strAddress = objWorksheet.Cells.Find(What:=strPrimarySearchColumn).Address
    strAddress = Mid(strAddress, 2, 1)
    area = objWorksheet.Columns(strAddress & ":" & strAddress) 'Range over the Column
    For Each range In area
        'If both criteria in the same Row are True then get the result
        If range.Value2.ToString = criteria1 And range.Offset(0, Offset_Krit2).Value = criteria2 Then
            twoStrSearch = range.Offset(0, Offset_result).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    twoStrSearch = "--" 'if nothing found result is "--"
End Function
```

The Eroor is happening in the For Each loop if he Compars the Cell Values with the Criteria1 and 2.

I stuck now for a while and i thought maybe some of you have an Idea!

Comment: `strAddress = Mid(strAddress, 2, 1)` this is the wrong way to get the address. it will fail for say `$AA$1`

Comment: Another Tip. `objWorksheet.Columns(strAddress & ":" & strAddress)` Why do you want to loop through all the cells (1048576 if xl2007+) in that column? Find the last row of that column and then construct your rnage.

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: Thank you for the Tip with the adress. I didn't thought of that. And to the Other tip i will implement that asap. thanks for the tips

Comment: in fact I had the new propsed code ready but @varocarbas had already posted an answer :p

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: to get the last row i wrote that line of code
intLastUsedCell = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
I know there are many ways to get the last cell, but i'm never sure with is the best way...
and thanks for your efforts

Comment: That is correct but instead of  "A", you can use the Column number which your search can return. `tempRange.Column` You don't need the `.Address` property at all :)

Comment: Let me post an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `For Each Loop` has two major problems: it iterates through all the ranges in a column without specifying that you actually want cells (a column is a range, a bunch of cells is a range, etc.), by default, it assumes that you want to iterate through whole columns and thus `.Value2` triggers an error (it cannot be applied to many cells). Also you are using `.ToString` without confirming that the value in the given cell is not null (not `Nothing`). Corrected code:

```
For Each range In area.Cells
    'If both criteria in the same Row are True then get the result
    If (range.Value2 IsNot Nothing) Then
        If range.Value2.ToString = criteria1 And range.Offset(0, Offset_Krit2).Value = criteria2 Then
            twoStrSearch = range.Offset(0, Offset_result).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Also there are some other problems with your code, for example:

```
strAddress = objWorksheet.Cells.Find(What:=strPrimarySearchColumn).Address
```

This line would trigger an error in case of not finding what is expected. A more proper way would be:

```
strAddress = ""
Dim tempRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = objWorksheet.Cells.Find(What:=strPrimarySearchColumn)
If (tempRange IsNot Nothing) Then
    strAddress = tempRange.Address
End If
```

You can get the row/column directly from the range (`tempRange`), instead using your current method. Please, refer to the Siddharth Rout's commment above.

Comment: Thank you very much. What you said was right and it works now fine. You guys are as usual the best.

Comment: @varoarbas. Thank you for the Tip with the adress. Will include that in the code.

Comment: @Moosli (varoCarbas :)) The whole point of helping you out here is giving you a general hint of what you are doing wrong. Using the Find method in this way is too dangerous; additionally, I understood from the Siddharth Rout's comment that your original approach was wrong (didn't realised about it by my own). By the way... he has written a new advice right now...

Comment: + 1 nicely explained. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks. Your contribution was also pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

**Not for Points (Only for explanation purpose)**

**Summary.**

1. The way you are extracting address will give you error if the search text is in say Col `AA1`
2. You don't need address to construct your range. You can use the Column number.
3. No point looping though all the cells (1048576 in case of xl2007+) Construct your relevant range by finding the last row in the search column

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

**Code: (Tried and Tested in VS 2010 Ultimate + Office 2010 Prof.)**

Try this. I have commented the code so let me know if there is anything which doesn't make sense.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '~~> Open relevant file
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx")

        '~~> Display Excel
        xlApp.Visible = True

        '~~> Set your first worksheet
        objWorksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        Dim Ret = twoStrSearch("1", "text-x", "TextNumber", -1, 1)

        MsgBox (Ret)

        '~~> Close the File
        xlWorkBook.Close (False)

        '~~> Quit the Excel Application
        xlApp.Quit()

        '~~> Clean Up
        releaseObject (objWorksheet)
        releaseObject (xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject (xlApp)
    End Sub

    Function twoStrSearch(ByVal criteria1 As String, ByVal criteria2 As String, ByVal strPrimarySearchColumn As String,
    ByVal Offset_Krit2 As Integer, ByVal Offset_result As Integer) As String
        Dim area As Excel.Range = Nothing
        Dim range As Excel.Range = Nothing
        Dim aCell As Excel.Range = Nothing
        Dim ColNo As Integer, lRow As Integer

        '~~> Find which column as the search text
        aCell = objWorksheet.Cells.Find(What:=strPrimarySearchColumn)

        '~~> Set it to "--" in case nothing is found
        twoStrSearch = "--"

        '~~> if found
        If aCell IsNot Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the column number
            ColNo = aCell.Column

            '~~> Get last row of that column
            lRow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, ColNo).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

            '~~> Construct your range from row 2 onwards. Row1 has headers
            area = objWorksheet.range(objWorksheet.Cells(2, ColNo), objWorksheet.Cells(lRow, ColNo))

            For Each range In area
                'If both criteria in the same Row are True then get the result
                If range.Value2.ToString = criteria1 And range.Offset(, Offset_Krit2).Value = criteria2 Then
                    twoStrSearch = range.Offset(, Offset_result).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        releaseObject (area)
        releaseObject (range)
        releaseObject (aCell)

        Return twoStrSearch
    End Function

    '~~> Release the objects
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: ok thanks for that you deserve a +1 from me as wel. now i know what you mean.
just realised that the function need a bit of a time to go through 17'000 rows ;)